# Querying Dimensional Model or schema using Java and SQL

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, olap, star-schema

I have a star schema with information/data and I want to write the sql query to pull data from the star schema and then embedd that sql in java application. where can I start from? or are there tutorials that can help me to write java application that can be pulling data from Dimensional Model? Like the way it is MDX Microsoft analysis services?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask" - as it stands, this question is a poor fit. It is _very_ broad, asks for resources outside SO, and you could find the answer by a quick Google.

Comment: Is there a way java framework  or tutorial to query data from star schema (Dimensional Model) using JAVA and SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be clear about a few things:

**Analysis Services** is an OLAP engine. It has preprocessed data stored in it, which is extracted using MDX. The Analysis Services pulls data from transactional database tables, which are organized in a dimensional model.

Now if you want to pull data from dimensional model using Java you can make a view or write custom SQL on the dimensional model and query that to get relevant data. This will be just like querying tables in database. However if you want to query the OLAP engine you use MDX to query. In .net you have adomd for querying in MDX.

Comment: I want to query star schema that is more like ROLAP which is not compiled.

Comment: Sure in that case just make some view or write custom quries and use them. Forget that star schema is feeding OLAP